# Integrating SWIG in Eclipse

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

Is there a plugin for eclipse IDE where I can run my SWIG module.
I'm trying to work in Windows, so can anyone tell me any available plugins for working with SWIG inside Eclipse?

Also I need to run C/C++ programs, so an IDE is the best way to work.

I don't want to use Microsoft Visual C++.

SWIG code:

```
   %module test
    %{
      int fact(int num);
    %}
```

Java code:

```
class Runme{
       public static void main(String argv[])
            {

              test.fact(100);
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to add something like:

```
$ swig -java interface.i
```

to the eclipse build process. maybe take a look at:

[Eclipse adding your own build command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976610/eclipse-adding-your-own-build-command)

I think eclipse should be fine for C/C++ dev

I use emacs instead for everything (C, Java, Android projects) but there's a bit of a learning curve involved