# Automatic commit on successful build ("breadcumbs")?

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea, continuous-integration, build-automation

Does anybody know if there is a way to automatically commit a project (a directory) just after a successful build from within an IDE? That is: something like a continous integration system, just lighter and better fit for a low-ceremony, "solo development" scenario.

I'm particularly interested in any solution that can work with IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) and GIT for Android projects (Java/Ant/Maven) but I'm also interested in other solutions (Eclipse, Netbeans, SVN, Hg, etc.). I'm also interested in a more general discussion on this topic (it is a good/bad idea, it can be done this way or this other, etc.).

I'm also open to code-based solutions (scripts, plug-ins, etc.). In particular, does anybody know if IntelliJ IDEA offers any "hook" for executing a script just before/after a menu command?

RATIONALE: I'm using IDEA to make a long series of small (but painful) experiments on an existing Android project and I would like to be able to go back step-by-step when needed using GIT (each step being represented by one of the previous successful builds). Call it "breadcrumbs programming" if you like.

Please note: I do know that this can be easily obtained with Ant/Maven/GIT/many-other-tools from the command line. I just want to see if it is possible to do it from within any of the IDEs I'm used to. And yes: I know I should commit often. I do it. I'm just tired to do it by hand.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html

Comment: Auto-commiting sounds like a bad idea to me because those commits would just bundle random changes without a useful commit message. And may include runtime errors.

Comment: I would like to find a tool smart enough to ask the user for a commit message (or, at least, to add a timestamp as a commit message). Please note that I'm not intentioned to use this tool to replace the usual best-practices-oriented GIT workflow. Rather, I want to use it to complement it. Between any two hand-made commits, I would like to find a sequence of automatic ones. I just want a finer granularity and a better control. (Runtime errors can be present even in hand-performed commits. It just depends on how deeply you test your code before commiting).

Comment: Eclipse's [Local History](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm) keeps a log of all changes to files you edit.

Comment: @andrew Eclipse's Local History is a nice tool but it is not what I hoped to find. The problem is that saving history on a per-file basis, in synchro with the file saving operation, is the wrong way to deal with this issue. I want to be able to revert to a safe state of the whole system (a working build), not to a previously saved version of a single file. Thanks for the contribution, anyway.

Comment: @CrazyCoders Well, TeamCity's Delayed Commit is not what I whoped to find but is nevertheless a very interesting tool (and a big step forward in the right direction, IMHO). I will keep it into consideration. Thanks.

Comment: I hope, you will come to a contrary decision sooner or later: commit, build, tag/bookmark on build's results as **more natural** workflow

Comment: Yes, sure, this is the most widely accepted workflow (the same I use, actually). Despite this, I would like to keep any non-working (aborted) build out of my GIT local repository and out of my GIT hystory file (at least when automatic commits are involved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like that this is not (yet) possible with IntelliJ IDEA, even if there is a very similar feature request sleeping since 2007: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5755 .

As long as I can see, the only IDE that currently offers a hook for executing a pre/post-build script *in its own GUI* is Eclipse, thanks to its "Builders" dialog:

[Eclipse adding your own build command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976610/eclipse-adding-your-own-build-command)

Both IDEA and NetBeans rely on Ant targets (only) for this kind of pre/post-build processing tasks. See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html .

Unfortunately, there is not yet a real integration between Ant and GIT (even if there are a few projects out there) so either you have to rely on a OS command (a process fork) or you can try to use JGit (http://eclipse.org/jgit/).

Another possible solution would be to modify the existing IDE GIT plug-in and make it able to accept pre/post-commit tasks or scripts (Eclipse, NetBeans and IDEA use plug-ins to interact with GIT).

Most likely, for the task at hand I will rely on my (old and tired) hands or on an Ant script.

In any case, IMHO, the "right" way to perform this kind of automatic commit would be the following:

1. Build the project (via Ant/Maven or via the IDE internal build system)
2. Ask the user for a commit message (or generate a message based on date and time)
3. Commit the source tree

Of course, a failed build should abort the remaining operations.

This would/should/ought NOT replace the normal, hand-performed, flow of commits. It should complement it, instead (maybe using a seperated GIT local repository or a separated branch).

Comment: **Why** do you want stem the tide in the commit-policy?

Comment: Well, I do not want to stop anything. I just would like to have a second, automatic mechanism to commit my changes, beside the regular one, to be used when I have to make a lot of small changes to a code base in a short period of time. More a convenience than a need.