# Run a script after succesfull compilation

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a JAVA project, every time when I made some changes I have to compile the code and after compiling I have to copy the jars files to a localhost location. The copying is done manually with a console command.

I was wondering if there is a option in Eclipse to automate the copying process after a successful compilation of the code so i don't have to copy the files myself. I was thinking about invoking a little script.

1. Is this possible?
2. Where to configure this in eclipse?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Google "eclipse post build script".

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976610/eclipse-adding-your-own-build-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on the project in eclipse and select "Properties"
2. Select "Builders" and then "New..."
3. In "Choose configuration type" window select "Program" and click
   "Ok"
4. In "Edit launch configuration properties" window set location to
   your script, working directory (probably it will be project
   directory) and arguments (if needed)
5. On Build Options tab check "During manual builds" and/or "During
   auto builds" Click "Ok" twice

Answer (score -1):

Just throwing out an alternative by suggesting creating a symlink to the jar file.