# How develop QT project with Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

The QT's Eclipse——integration plugin has been invalid.

Is there any method that we can just build a project involved QT within the Eclipse CDT?

Like , I got the QT's library and header files and the moc , then if I just design the GUI with code , I can directly debug and compile the QT project in the Eclipse CDT .

Is there any solution ? I see the NetBeans can do this ,but it seems just support to QT4 but not to QT5

thanks .

Answer (score 2):

You can just add Qt headers and libs directories as global Eclipse paths for C++ [includes](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm) directories and for [libraries](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm).

For Qt 5 it's folders `include` and `lib` in the root Qt installation folder.

[Updated] Because to generate correct makefiles from .pro file you need to run qmake everytime, I suggest to look into the direction of [custom build commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976610/eclipse-adding-your-own-build-command).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775398/eclipse-qt-and-c-project-is-it-possible) it's not recommended to try to do this directly.